# Can postMessage in doInit with huge dataset cause any memory issues in Chrome?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, performance

We have a VF page which has datatable initialized. This VF page is embedded inside an `iframe` in a lightning component.

For now case records are 200-300, so the page loads quickly as loading of iframe takes time and on `doinit` of component I already fetch all the cases and keep it with me to post a message when the iframe has loaded.

```
doFetchInitialData: function (objComponent) {
    const fetchCaseSummaryCases = objComponent.get("c.fetchAllCasesForCaseSummary");
    fetchCaseSummaryCases.setParams({
        'accountId': objComponent.get('v.recordId')
    });
    fetchCaseSummaryCases.setCallback(this, function(objResponse) {
        if (objResponse.getState() === 'SUCCESS') {
            const strCaseBulkData = objResponse.getReturnValue();
            const strAccountId = objComponent.get('v.recordId');
            const objIntervalForCasePage = setInterval(function() {
                const idIframe = objComponent.get('v.caseFrameId');
                try {
                    if (idIframe !== undefined && idIframe !== null && document.getElementById(idIframe) !== undefined && document.getElementById(idIframe) !== null && document.getElementById(idIframe).dataIsLoaded === 1) {
                        clearInterval(objIntervalForCasePage);
                        const objNewPageFrame = document.getElementById(idIframe).contentWindow;
                        const objPostMessageResponse = {
                            strIdDestination: 'SendCaseDataToPage',
                            objParameters: {
                                strCaseBulkData: strCaseBulkData,
                                strAccountId: strAccountId
                            }
                        };
                        objNewPageFrame.postMessage(JSON.stringify(objPostMessageResponse), '*');
                    }
                } catch (objException) {
                    clearInterval(objIntervalForCasePage);
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(fetchCaseSummaryCases);
},
```

Let say the case records say cases increases in production, like (2000-3000). Will this cause issues for the above code? Can post message handles big dataset?

NOTE: for 200-300 records the size is almost `322kb`

Comment: I would question in the first place why show 2000-3000 records? can you not  look at pagination to limit the number of records?

Comment: pagination has been implemented by `datatable`, but for pagination to work we have to load full set of data and give instructions to datatable library that we want only these number of records to display in one page, and then only datatable pagination will decide how much pages it want to show.

Comment: The dataset should go at once because we have search functionality  that would fail if whole data is not loaded at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Client Payload Data Limit Use action.setParams() to set data for an
>   action to be passed to a server-side controller.
>
> The framework batches the actions in the queue into one server
>   request. The request payload includes all of the actions and their
>   data serialized into JSON. The request payload limit is **4 MB**.

I wouldn't advise going over 3000 records since you might hit the data transfer limit.

[Documentation link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm)

Comment: Thats the request payload, but what is the response payload limit from enqueue action.

Comment: I think they are subject to usual Apex limits, in this case **6mb** max.

Comment: But shouldn't enqueuaction fall under async operation and have **12 mb** limit?

Comment: I don't think the aysnc operation of the JS to server action request is the same as async apex jobs.